# Construct SQL query with a lot of parameters from configuration

Tags: c++, mysql, configuration

I have implemented an interface through which one can select, update and remove items of the `Account` class in a MySQL database. For the three functions I'm preparing statements.

The database, column and table names are all configured in a settings file.

Because of this I have to call the interface which gets the configuration from the settings file while preparing my query. This gives me a huge code block of code with little string concatenations in between:

```
updateStmt(connection->prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO " + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                            PTH_PART_STORAGE_TABLE_NAME)
            + "(" + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_SYSTEM_IDCOL) + ","
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_OWNERCOL) + ","
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAMECOL) + ","
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTIONCOL) + ","
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORDCOL) + ","
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BALANCECOL) + ","
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_LOCKEDCOL) + ","
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORDEDTRANSACTIONSCOL)
            + "," + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_SYSTEM_CHANGEDCOL) + ","
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_SYSTEM_CREATEDCOL) + ","
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_SYSTEM_DELETEDCOL)
            + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),NOW(),NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_OWNERCOL) + "=VALUES("
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_OWNERCOL) + "), "
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAMECOL) + "=VALUES("
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAMECOL) + "), "
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                             PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTIONCOL)
            + "=VALUES(" + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                          PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTIONCOL)
            + "), " + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                     PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORDCOL)
            + "=VALUES(" + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                          PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORDCOL)
            + "), " + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                     PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BALANCECOL)
            + "=VALUES(" + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                          PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BALANCECOL)
            + "), " + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                     PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_LOCKEDCOL)
            + "=VALUES(" + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                          PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_LOCKEDCOL)
            + "), " + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                     PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORDEDTRANSACTIONSCOL)
            + "=VALUES(" + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
                                          PTH_PART_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORDEDTRANSACTIONSCOL)
            + "), " + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_SYSTEM_CHANGEDCOL) + "=NOW()"
            + GETSET(PTH_STORAGE_SYSTEM_DELETEDCOL) + "=NULL"
    ))
```

`GETSET(x)` is a define for `settingsCtrl.readSetting(x)` to shorten the call. `PTH_STORAGE_...` and `PTH_PART_...` are defines for the XPaths to the configuration value.

`PTH_STORAGE_ACCOUNT PTH_PART_STORAGE_TABLE_NAME` is an XPath to the account section and the configuration value for the table name.

I think it is obvious that building a query like this seems a bit *wrong*, but I'm not sure if there is a more concise way to prepare a query with so much parameters.

Is there?

Comment: May be you could split it up into different functions and concatenate the results?  Also, if someone will want to concatenate another *string literal* in the beginning, it's gonna do something (not) funny.

Comment: @Incomputable I was thinking of this already, but I guess it won't reduce the above code very much. When I loop over the parameters I would have to introduce a lot of if-else-statements to consider the cases like `=NOW()`. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: you could write some sophisticated iterator. Though I think it might escalate complexity quite a bit.  Or you could use multiple iterators on different ranges. The key here is to understand the pattern in which those things come. If it is chaotic, then I believe there is no way to do anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to be blunt as it stands it is totally unreadable and thus unmaintainable.

You should break that up into multiple variables that are combined in a way that is readable.

```
std::stringstream columnName;
std::stringstream statement;

columnNames << storageAccount << ", "
            << storageName    << ", "
            << storageDesc    << ", "
            << storagePass    << ", "
            << storageBalance << ", "
            << storageLoc     << ", "
            << storageAccount << ", "
            << storageChanged << ","
            << storageDelCol;

statement << "INSERT INTO " << table 
          << "     (" << columnNames.str() << ") "
          << "     VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW(), NULL) "
          << "ON DUPLICATE KEY  UPDATE "
          <<       storageAccount << " = VALUES(" << storageAccount << "), "
          <<       storageName    << " = VALUES(" << storageName    << "), "
          <<       storageDesc    << " = VALUES(" << storageDesc    << "), "
          <<       storagePass    << " = VALUES(" << storagePass    << "), "
          <<       storageBalance << " = VALUES(" << storageBalance << "), "
          <<       storageLoc     << " = VALUES(" << storageLoc     << "), "
          <<       storageAccount << " = VALUES(" << storageAccount << "), "
          <<       storageChanged << " = NOW(),"
          <<       storageDelCol  << " = NULL";
```

Comment: Although this is in principle the same approach as in my question (not reverting to introduce new functions/loops/...) it looks much cleaner and I see the gain in maintainability and readability.